# Programmatically attaching files

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have created the "Gallery" content type, and added two fields: "photo," and "document." I then used the following code for uploading a file in the "document" field:

```
$file = file_save_upload('document', array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('txt doc'), // Validate extensions.
));

// If the file passed validation:
if ($file) {
// Move the file, into the Drupal file system
if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
 // $file->file_display = 1;
  $file = file_save($file);

} else {
  $output = t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.');
}       
 } else {
$output = t('No file was uploaded.');
 }
```

I am attaching this file to the node using the following code:

```
$customNode->field_document[$customNode->language][0] = (array)$file;
```

When I call `node_submit()` function, I get the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field_document_display' cannot be null

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 29):

I usually don't throw the `(array)$file` line because really the only thing the field data needs is the fid, description and display. So I usually do the following:

```
$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array(
  'fid' => $file->fid,
  'display' => 1,
  'description' => '',
);
node_save( $node );
```

This way if the display is required, I don't get an error. But that's just me...

Comment: Confusing to me why it doesn't have default values.

Comment: You don't see default values because this is direct assignment.

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is almost right; however, in some cases it requires that you also set display and description.

To make your code work do this:

```
$file = file_save_upload('document', array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('txt doc'), // Validate extensions.
));

// If the file passed validation:
if ($file) {
// Move the file, into the Drupal file system
if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
 // $file->file_display = 1;
  $file = file_save($file);
  //set the extra values needed to make node_save work
  $file->display = 1;
  $file->description = "";
} else {
  $output = t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.');
}       
 } else {
$output = t('No file was uploaded.');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the key here are those lines

```
$file->display = 1;
$file->description = "";
```

as Eric van Eldik pointed out. I was struggling with the exact same issue, adding just

```
$file->display = 1;
```

didn't help, but

```
$file->description = "";
```

made my day.

Answer (score 0):

For adding file programmatically to node you can use

```
$managed = TRUE; // Whether or not to create a Drupal file record
$filename = 'public://imdb-cast-' . time() . '.jpg';
$iamge_file = system_retrieve_file($url,$filename , $managed);
if($iamge_file){
$file = file_load(db_query('SELECT MAX(fid) FROM {file_managed}')->fetchField());
$node->field_image['und'][0] = (array) $file;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to paste my solution here as well, I needed to create a new node, and upload an image programmatically.

```
$filepath = variable_get('file_public_path') . '/xmas_banner.jpg';
$file_temp = file_get_contents($filepath);
$file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, file_default_scheme() . '://' .'xmas_banner_nl.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'carousel'; // custom content type
$node->title = 'XMAS NL';
$node->field_banner_image['und'][0] = (array) $file_temp;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->status = 0;
$node->active = 0;
$node->promote = 0;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach multiple files programmatically in Drupal 8:

```
foreach ($fileIds as $fid) {
  $node->field_images[] = [
    'target_id' => $fid,
    'alt' => 'ALT TEXT',
    'title' => 'TITLE TEXT'
  ];
}
$node->save();
```