# Import files into a file field in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, files, importing-exporting

I have a content type that accepts a PDF document as a file attachment.  I have a bunch of entries that currently have no attachment, but I have the files for each entry and need to associate the files with each of their respective entries.

Currently, all of those files are stored in public://publications, so they're already in the public file path where they should be, I just need to "hook them up".

Rather than hack this with Ruby which I would normally do, I'd like to kick the bad habit and use the Drupal API.  I've looked at the following articles:

- [Programmatically attaching files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10220/programmatically-attaching-files-to-a-node-in-drupal-7)
- http://drupal.org/node/330421

..but haven't been able to really wrap my head around it.

Curious if others have dealt with this situation and what they've done to address it.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've got the files copying as they should be.  However, I'm not encountering an error, and the error happens during the `node_save` call.

Here is the error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1330491978
)
 in drupal_write_record() (line 6975 of /var/www/website/drupal-7.4/includes/common.inc).
```

And here is the code.

```
$node = node_load($bib_value->nid);

$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = basename($filepath);
$file->filepath = $filepath;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($filepath);
$file->filesize = filesize($filepath);
$file->uid = 1;
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->uri = $filepath;
$file = file_copy($file,'public://publications',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// THIS IS A PROBLEM LINE
$node->field_publication_attachment[LANGUAGE_NONE] = $file;

node_save($node);
```

If I comment out the line labeled `THIS IS A PROBLEM LINE` then no error occurs, but that obviously isn't desirable because that means it's completing but without attaching my file to the node!  Help!

**SOLUTION**

```
$node = node_load($bib_value->nid);

$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = basename($filepath);
$file->filepath = $filepath;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($filepath);
$file->filesize = filesize($filepath);
$file->uid = 1;
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->uri = $filepath;
$file->display = 1;
$file->description = '';
$file = file_copy($file,'public://publications',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

$node->field_publication_attachment[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array)$file;

node_save($node);
```

Needed to set `display` and `description` on `$file` as well as cast `$file` as an array when adding it to the attachment field.  All worked smoothly after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently working on the exact same thing, except using photos.  If you click my profile name, you will see a series of questions related to learning how to do what you are asking to do.

I was able to easily accomplish the code to loop through all the files in my folder and add them to my nodes.

```
$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = basename($local_path);
$file->filepath = $local_path;
$file->uri = $local_path;
$file->filemime = $mime;
$file->filesize = filesize($local_path);

// Set this at the very beginning to correspond to USER you want posting items.
$file->uid = $uid; 
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);

$images[] = array(
'fid' => $file->fid,
'alt' => $page_data['title'],
'title' => $page_data['title']
);
```

Comment: Did you run into any PDO issues, namely `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column fid cannot be null`?

Comment: I did - see the added source code above. Calling 'file_save' will return the object with $file->fid properly filled out based on the insert into the database.  Notice my images array now can properly use $file->fid so that, on node_save($node) you should not get that error. Later in the code $images is assigned to $node->files like this:  $node->field_product_images[LANGUAGE_NONE] = $images; yours would be $node->my_file_field[LANGUAGE_NONE] = $my_files_array. Note, your file field may need different attributes. Use devel to see what fields need populating. You wont need alt and title fields.

Comment: I updated my post with a new error message, this time referring to the uri.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing it:

```
$entity = entity_load($id);
$data = file_get_contents($localpath);
$destination = file_create_filename(basename($localpath), file_default_scheme() . '://yourdir/' );
$file = file_save_data($data, $destination);
$entity->field_attachment[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array)$file;
$entity->save();
```

Comment: The next time I need to do something similar I will try this.  It's very short and concise.